# Python Script Invalid Syntax error on a downloaded script

Tags: python

i want to try a script from a GameStateIntegration

```
def sendHealthStatus(health): # Send health status to arduino
  if health == 100:
    arduino.write('h')
    arduino.write(str(health))
  if health < 100 and >= 10:
    arduino.write('h0')
    arduino.write(str(health))
  if health < 10 and >= 0:
    arduino.write('h00')
    arduino.write(str(health))`
```

but i get an invalid syntax for

```
if health < 100 and >= 10:
```

in fact of the '=' sign, when I remove it , it tells me that the '>' is the error

what is wrong with that script ?

Greetings from Germany
Björn

Comment: Well, that is invalid syntax. So apparently you downloaded a script that doesn't work. Not your fault, but you'll probably want to avoid trying to learn from examples that don't actually work.

Comment: Anyway, it's pretty easy to guess at what the code is _trying_ to do: `if health < 100 and health >= 10:`. Although really, that would be better written as `if 10 <= health < 100:`. Or, even better, [as an `if/elif/elif` chain so you don't need to keep checking the upper bounds](https://gist.github.com/abarnert/10e8ec80cbd6d51ce17e20bc556199c1).

Comment: Meanwhile, can you link to where you downloaded this from? If it's somewhere important, like the Arduino documentation, someone ought to file a bug report or equivalent. If it's just some random pastebin somewhere, just ignore it; there's lots of useless broken code in random pastebins.

Comment: There i got this code from : https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/4xt9rf/csgo_game_state_integration_arduino_project/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line with this:

```
if health < 100 and health >= 10:
```

(you need a value on each side of a comparison)

Comment: Python allows chained [comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), so you can just as well write `10 <= health < 100`.

Comment: okay the script works fine now ( i see the gamestate in the python command window) - the arduino flashes also at RX , but the LED wont work :( damn troubleshooting on "finished" scripts

Comment: @BjörnBräucker I seriously advise you to throw it out, it looks terrible.